# i am getting Same Values while commanding different values in C++ in [ int,float,char etc ]

Tags: c++

**input**

```
int main()
{
    int a; //declaration
    a=15; //initialisation

    cout<<"sizeofint"<<sizeof(a)<<endl\n;
    
    float b;
    cout<<"size of float"<<sizeof(b)<<endl;

    char c;
    cout<<"size of char"<<sizeof(c)<<endl;

    bool d;
    cout<<"size of bool"<<sizeof(d)<<endl;
```

**output**

```
size of int4
size of float4
size of char1
size of bool1
```

another example

```
int a; //declaration
    a=21; //initialisation

    cout<<"sizeofint"<<sizeof(a)<<endl\n;
    
    float b;
    cout<<"size of float"<<sizeof(b)<<endl;

    char c;
    cout<<"size of char"<<sizeof(c)<<endl;

    bool d;
    cout<<"size of bool"<<sizeof(d)<<endl;
```

**Output**

```
size of int4
size of float4
size of char1
size of bool1
```

both Outputs are same!!!
why?

Comment: Could you please clarify what you've expected to happen? Do you expect an integer (or any other datatype for that matter) to take up more space in memory when a larger value is stored in it? Do you know what `sizeof` does?

Comment: i removed output that is not produced by the posted code. If your question is only about `size of int4` vs `size of int4` you could remove more, the others is same code produces same output

Comment: That's assignment, not initialization. `int a = 15;` is initialization.

Answer (score 3):

I think there is a misunderstanding in the way how you think declarations work.No matter how big a number you put into `int` value (even if it is out of its bounds) compiler will still reserve the same amount of bytes, which is also dependent on your operating system architecture (typically, `32-bit` or `64-bit`). For example, `size_t` in a `32-bit` system has 4 bytes size when in `64-bit` it has 8 bytes size (the same thing goes for any pointer). For `int` value is it default to have 4 bytes( in ILP64 interface its gonna be double the size!). `Sizeof()` returns how much memory (in bytes) is reserved for a certain variable.